# BsInlineDatepicker not working in ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I want to use inline datepicker: 
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#inline-datepicker

But it is giving me an error: *Can't bind to 'bsValue' since it isn't a known property of 'bs-datepicker-inline'.*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
    <bs-datepicker-inline [bsValue]="bsInlineValue"></bs-datepicker-inline>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is my package.json file for the code.

```
{
"name": "angular",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "3.4.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-less": "^3.5.0",
    "gulp-minify": "2.1.0",
    "gulp-rev": "^8.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.2.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "3.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "less": "2.7.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "protractor-html-reporter": "^1.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
}
}
```

[image: error message]

[I am adding stackblitz link here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-tdcl6r)

Answer (score 0):

You should inject requered modules into `NgModule` of your project,

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

**UPDATE:**

Please update your package dependencies like below,

[Here is working stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-qpzvyn)

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.5",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already added that. bsDatepicker is working fine but bsInlineDatepicker is not working

Comment: @EeshaniPatel I just figured out your package versions are missing. Working on it.

Comment: I have added my package.json file. It is still not working.

Comment: @EeshaniPatel You should run **npm i** after your update. See here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-qpzvyn